# Could a CRC32 key with a most or least significant bit of 0 be valid?

Tags: crc32

I have a server receiving UDP packets with the payload being a number of CRC32 checksumed 4 byte words. The header in each UDP packet has a 2 byte field holding the "repeating" key used for the words in the payload. The way I understand it is that in CRC32 the keys must start and end with a 1 in the binary representation of the key. In other words the least and most significant bits of the key must be a 1 and not 0. So my issue is that I get, for example, the first UDP packet received has the key holding field reading 0x11BC which would have the binary representation 00010001 10111100. So the 1's are neither right nor left aligned to the key holding word. There are trailing 0's on both sides. Is my understanding on valid CRC32 keys wrong then? I ask as I'm trying to write the code to check each word using the key as is and it seems to always give a remainder meaning every word in the payload has an error and yet the instructions I've been given guarantee that the first packet received in the sample given has no errors.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a very similar problem. Perhaps you could be a bit of help if you don't mind. Here, we're using the "XOR Key" as the generator polynomial, correct? Are you supposed to do mod 2 division on every DWORD in the payload? How could this tell you exactly which bit is incorrect? To my understanding, CRC detects that an error exists, not exactly where the error occured.

Comment: I'm not an expert on CRC32 but I don't think you'd be able to tell exactly which bit is incorrect. Maybe the CRC32 experts could confirm if I'm right?

Comment: I think you're correct. I'm just a bit unsure about what is meant by the sequence number. How do you use this in your calculation? And also, I see your point about the XOR key. Did you ever figure anything out about that?

Comment: And also, if you can't tell which bit is incorrect, how can you calculate the "expected crc32" and the "received crc32"?

Comment: I didn't get to figure out how to work with the key. I tried using it to check each of the DWORDs for a remainder and found all of them gave remainders which is not what I expected. So my use of the key must have been wrong. To check for the expected CRC32 word you're somehow supposed to use the source file for the UDP packets. I tried printing it's binary out and looking for a relationship or common bytes between the first bytes in the source file, the first packet's payload and the key but found none. So I gave up on that part and probably failed the interview as a result. Good luck to you.

Comment: Yup, I'm in the same position as you. Thanks for the ideas. Were you able to figure out part 2 of the challenge at all? When I run the hidden .py file, It just says "Hint: The first input: h". Not sure where to go after that. I see that there's a lot of things encrypted in their source code, but I'm not sure how to get it out.

Comment: That I failed to figure out. I was out of time and had a problem with some of the imported modules in that source code like termios which is apparently only available on POSIX OS's. I'm on Windows so I just mailed them the progress I had made in unearthing that source code from the pdf. I basically flunked this interview but it seems others also found it challenging.

Comment: Ah yes, I had to download a virtual machine to run it on Linux. It is pretty challenging. I've sunk tens of hours into it, unfortunately. I have to turn it in on Wednesday. According to Glassdoor reviews, some people thought they did very well solving both challenges and still didn't hear back.

Comment: Good luck with your job search, man. I've submitted just under 700 applications and have only managed to receive one low-ball offer. Hopefully, we find employment soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is true that CRC polynomials always have the top and bottom bit set, often this is dealt with implicitly; a 32-bit CRC is actually a 33-bit calculation and the specified polynomial ordinarily omits the top bit.

So e.g. the standard quoted polynomial for a CCITT CRC16 is `0x1021`, which does not have its top bit set.

It is normal to include the LSB, so if you're certain you know which way around the polynomial has been specified then either the top or the bottom bit of your word should be set.

However, for UDP purposes you've possibly also made a byte ordering error on one side of the connection or the other? Network byte ordering is conventionally big endian whereas most processors today are little — is one side of the link switching byte order but not the other?

Comment: Tommy, maybe I misunderstood you but I was referring to the key that is used to check for errors in the received CRC32'd data.

Comment: Okay, so I've misunderstood, that's definitely true. Answer will be either deleted or amended shortly. But I'm checking a whole bunch of sites and nobody seems to use the term 'key' to refer to part of a CRC32. Are you referring to the polynomial?

Comment: Answer changed — again, I completely misunderstood first time around and that's my error. If it's still no help then deleting it might be the most responsible step.

Comment: The task I'm working on is not a real life problem. It's a coding challenge so you're provided with a file that has the prerecorded UDP packets with their errors and a script that sends these packets to the local ip address. The first packet is guaranteed to have no errors. My task is to write code that receives these packets on a local port and detect the CRC32 words with errors. So the part of my code I'm having a problem with is taking the keys in the headers and using modulo 2 division into the CRC32's words to see which will give remainders and label these erroneous.

Comment: So when I get a key like 0x11BC I'm wondering why I have 2 trailing 0's after the least significant 1? I've stepped through my modulo 2 division code and it seems correct but remainders always result indicating errors in all the CRC32'd words that are supposed to be correct.

Comment: @open it's definitely `0x11bc` and not `0xbc11`? You're using [`ntohs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) or your language's equivalent?

Comment: I've just looked at that last comment I made and I made a mistake in writing the script sends to a local ip address. The sending script actually sends to the local host. The sending script and the code I'm writing to receive the packets run on the same computer. Will there be any conversions from network byte order to host byte order in that case? I looked at the code for the sending script and it just opens a socket in Python and sends to localhost at a specific port. My code listens and receives on that port on this same host.

Comment: You're probably right in saying the key is as it seems because the rest of the packet when received and inspected conforms to what the instructions in the challenge specify. Just those trailing 0's have me puzzled and suspecting I should somehow process the key a little before passing it to the function that's doing the checking in order to get expected results.